# How to do something after perform a segue finished?

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

I'm using a segue in storyboard to present a modal view controller. Instead of segue I can use presentViewController:animated:completion to do something in the completion block.
But now I don't  know when the segue is finished, and where to put my completion codes

Here are the codes I used before:

```
presentViewController:modalViewController animated:YES completion:^{

    modalViewController.items = items;
    [modalViewController showItem:itemdIndex];
}];
```

I need to call modalViewController method from outside.

Answer (score 3):

you have to subclass `UIStoryboardSegue` and implement the perform method in it. After that, in storyboard you set the class of the segue to the one you just created.

Or You can place the code in `ViewDidLoad` or `ViewWillAppear` methods of the view you are segueing.

Best is to go for `ViewDidLoad` in this way your code would be executed only once when the view would be loaded first.

Comment: Both `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear` will be called before the segue is finished, right?

Answer (score 1):

Put them in `viewWillAppear:` in the view controller you're segueing to.

Note: If you're adding the view controllers to a stack (like inside a `UINavigationController`), `viewWillAppear:` will get called every time the view controller is segued to (even if you're coming back to it from another view controller). IF you want your code to run only once (when it initially loads), put it in `viewDidLoad` instead.

Comment: I add the codes I used before to question, I need to call the method of presentedViewController from outside.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it programmatically:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MyStoryboardName", bundle: nil)
let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "someViewController")
self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: {
    // put your code that you want to execute after perform segue finished
})
```